# Assign values to OpenCv matrix all at once

Tags: c++, opencv, mat

I simply want to set the elements of a matrix to a specific value, without doing deep or even shallow copies.

As far as I’ve understood

```
myMat = Mat::ones(rows, cols, CV_32SC1)*10;
```

will allocate space on disk for a new matrix (same data type and dimension in this case), set values, release old data and then make myMat point to the new data.
Instead

```
myMat = 10;
```

will just set values to the original data, without new allocation and release.
It is equivalent to

```
myMat.setTo(10);
```

which in turn corresponds to old style:

```
cvSet(myMat, cvScalar(0));
```

Am I wrong in some point?

Comment: You are right except for the last `cvScalar(_10_)`. That was the only question?

Comment: Yes it was, but it is very important for me.
Thank you.